# How to trigger multiple c# functions in a particular time in specific order using azure function?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions

I have created two functions which triggered on everyday at specific time (2:00 AM) but both functions triggered independently on specific time in azure function.

I have tried following working example which function1 and function2 triggered everyday at specific time (2:00 AM)

```
[FunctionName("Function1")]
public static void Method1([TimerTrigger("0 0 2 * * *")] TimerInfo myTimer, ILogger log)
{
    log.LogInformation($"Function 1: {DateTime.Now}");
}
[FunctionName("Function2")]
public static void Method2([TimerTrigger("0 0 2 * * *")] TimerInfo myTimer, ILogger log)
{
    log.LogInformation($"Function 2: { DateTime.Now}");
}
```

but both function triggered independently,

For example First time I executed code, following function order was displayed which is expected result -

```
Function1: 5/11/2021 02:00:00 AM
Function2: 5/11/2021 02:00:00 AM
```

but Second time I again execute code than following function order was displayed -

```
Function2: 5/11/2021 02:00:00 AM
Function1: 5/11/2021 02:00:00 AM
```

EXPECTED RESULT:-

Both functions should be triggered at 2:00 AM such that function1 triggers first and after that function2 should be trigger as following order -

```
Function1: 5/11/2021 02:00:00 AM
Function2: 5/11/2021 02:00:00 AM
```

How to trigger multiple functions in a particular time in specific order using azure function?

Comment: Durable functions will do that for you. Or just combine the two functions into one.

Comment: Why would you even expect a particular order? What part of the documentation states that?

Comment: @lan kemp I expect number of functions call particular order because those function will trigger HubSpot API calls and HubSpot platform have limit for number of API calls per seconds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although you set the Function1 at first and set Function2 at second, but they will be triggered independently as you test.

If you want them be triggered in order, why not put two function execution code into one function(execute the first part of code then execute the second part of code) ?

Or another option is modify the cron expression of second function to: `0 1 2 * * *`, then it will be trigger at 2:01 AM.